# Spring MVC 2.x with ajax using jquery etc.

Tags: ajax, spring, model-view-controller

```
I have a scenario of ajax call to spring mvc controller to get the text.
```

Please provide an example of this. 
I have to use Spring 2.x not spring 3.x.

```
like:

Model m=new HashMap();
m.put("textToAjax","Sample");
return new ModelAndView("",m);

And i need to get this text, ie Sample on my jsp text box.

Tha ajax call is like

 $.ajax({
        type:"GET",
        url:"test.hmtl?method=getTextName",
                .............
});

Please correct this and help me with full example.enter code here
```

Answer (score 2):

here's how I currently do and it works:

Map the test.html to a TestController:

```
/test.html=TestController
```

Declare TestController in the dispatcher-servlet.xml:

```
<bean id="TestController" class="com.aeps.planair.fo.controller.TestController"></bean>
```

Create a simple view file "result.jsp" for displaying ajax response:

```
${result}
```

Map this view:

```
result.(class)=org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView
result.url=/WEB-INF/ajaxview/result.jsp
```

Develop the TestController:

```
public class DateController implements Controller {

    @Override
    public ModelAndView handleRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
        String nowTime = Date().toString();
            ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("result");
            modelAndView.addObject("result", nowTime);
            return modelAndView;
    }
}
```

Now, in your html file, you can call the TestController like this:

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function doAjax() {
            $.ajax({
                url : 'test.html',
                success : function(data) {
                    $('#time').html(data);
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <button id="demo" onclick="doAjax()" title="Button">Get the time!</button>
    <div id="time"></div>
</body>
```

In this example, the time will be displayed each time you click on the "Get time" button.

Best regards